# Zend_Controller_Router_Route Chaining Problem with more than 3 url parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework, architecture, routes

I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong, but I'm attempting to setup module routing based on sub domain. Otherwise the routing is standard. The following works until I add more than 3 parameters in the URL:

This is within a controller plugin

```
...
public function routeStartup() {
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $pathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route (
            ':controller/:action/*',
            array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index'
            )
    );

    $hostRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(':module.domain.com');

    $chainedRoute = $hostRoute->chain($pathRoute);

    $router->addRoute('host', $chainedRoute);
    ...
}
```

http://module.domain.com/controllerName/actionName/param1 *works*
http://module.domain.com/controllerName/actionName/param1/param2 *does not work*

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the framework routing code.

See http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6654 for a fix.